# Implement session handler in Redis

Tags: php, session, redis

Hello I need shared SESSION PHP with NODE. So I decided use REDIS, I don't know it earlier. For client I choose Predis.

And now I have some issue, when we look into session handler source we can see that variable is store as string, why that ?

https://github.com/nrk/predis/blob/v0.8/lib/Predis/Session/SessionHandler.php

The first thing in my head was HASH, it seems obvious for me. There is any contraindications for that ?

Answer (score 0):

In redis everything is stored as key value pair whose basic type is string itself . You can always store your hash in form of json encoded string or as Sets in Redis.